# Google App Engine Flexible Environent - how to use env variables from app.yml when running locally

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

when i run the app locally, obviously the variables from app.yml are not injected into process.env , whats the correct way to get around this ?

runtime: nodejs
env: flex
   service: email

```
 env_variables:
   PUBSUB_TOPIC: dev-xxx

   PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN: <your-verification-token>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine Flexible - environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447698/google-app-engine-flexible-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to *not* use app.yaml for environment variables.  Instead, I suggest using [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf) and a json file like we do in the [samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/2-structured-data).