# Google App Engine Flexible - environment variables

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

if I have my circle-ci deplying to google with e.g. 'gcloud app deploy app.yaml' is there a simple way I can pass a dev / prod variable and have it replaced in my app.yml file below ?

Sure, I could have multiple app.dev.yml, app.dev.yml files etc but theres a lot of duplication involved unless I can just override some by using some sort of base app.yml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: email

env_variables:
  PUBSUB_TOPIC: dev-email-integration-email
  PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN: <your-verification-token>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there really isn't a good way to do this.  I'd actually suggest *not* using app.yaml for this purpose, and instead using a json file and [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf).  That's how we do it in all of our [nodejs samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/2-structured-data).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on how this works in practice?  Even with a config file, we need to somehow tell app engine which environment it's in, right?